# Linq to SQL and database driver relation

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, ado.net

I've recently "inherited" the maintenance and support of (quite old) project that stores and manipulates data in MS SQL databases using Linq to SQL. I have little to no experience in this field and recently a customer informed us that their data center is planning update of DB drivers AND disabling of SQL Native Client.

I've spent quite some time trying to understand the relations/version compatibility between ADO providers, DB drivers and Linq to SQL and honestly I feel like I'm missing the big picture. Connection string used to initiate DataContext instance is an OLEDB connection string but my understanding is too shallow to rule out usage of SQL Native Client.

If someone could point me in the right direction, that would be really great.

Comment: Not a coding question, you are asking about client versions. This should be a software engineering question imo?

Comment: Could be, but while client version compatibility is indeed the problem I'm trying to solve, it's not what I came here to ask (see the title and the last two paragraphs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq to SQL uses the .NET Framework's System.Data.SqlClient.  This is separate driver from SQL Native Client's ODBC and OleDB drivers, and is updated as part of Windows updates.